# Duplicated attribute inside input field using swagger

Tags: swagger

I'm having a problem using swagger[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbm3d.png) as you see i see the the atribute name duplicated, and i don't know why.

I want only one numeroMatricula inside the field text, I've tried everything a nothing works properly.Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the parameter definition from your OpenAPI YAML/JSON file?

Comment: I have the post so that through the swagger I can enter the different parameters as data, the problem is that inside the place holder I get the name of the attribute repeated 2 times instead of only once, I did a similar project like a month ago and i have no problema about the placeholder so  I am a little bit lost, Im new using swagger.